# Salesforce chatter REST api rate limits

Tags: rest-api, chatter, limits

I am new to the Salesforce platform. I want to create custom branding of chatter for our organization. I looked into the [limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/intro_rate_limits.htm) of chatter api and found out that, we are allowed to make one request per minute and 60 requests per hour(if I am not mistaken).

As salesforce mentioned the [Sforce-Limit-Info header](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/headers_api_usage.htm) returned in each request to REST api, so in order to get the usage count I have tested the chatter api feed using postman but unfortunately, chatter REST api is not returning the `limit-info-header`.

As I am using the developer edition scratch org the maximum api limit is 50,000 for 24 hours. when I am [requesting feed](http://services/data/v47.0/chatter/feeds/company/feed-elements) or posting a feed element while using REST api, the api usage is getting increment (usage found in Settings -> Company information), I think this usage count is for the organization(scratch org in my case) is shared among all users and apps of org, so if there are 40 persons using our custom chatter there is the higher probability that we will hit the maximum limit in less than 24 hours.

So is there is any way to build a custom chatter without hitting the api limits or I missed something?

Answer (score 2):

The Chatter API *rate limits* are distinct from the overall *API call limits*, and note that it is scoped to the user:

> For applications using a session ID from Salesforce, the rate limit is per user, per hour—there isn't a separate bucket for applications. All applications the user accesses with a session ID use this general quota. To take advantage of the per user, per application, per hour limit, use OAuth tokens.

Your application should authorize via OAuth. By doing so, you can take advantage of this scoping.

> When polling for feed updates, do not exceed one poll per minute (60 polls per hour *per user per application*). To return more results in 1 request, increase the page size.
>
> When polling for private messages, do not exceed 60 polls per hour *per user per application*.

Italics my inclusions to clarify the statements.